# How to get query for specific tags coincidences in MongoDB, in PHP?

Tags: php, mongodb, querying

I'm very new to MongoDB and I have the following database and what I need is retrieve **all** documents that have the "Canada" in the **tags** field. How can this be achieved in PHP?
[image: MongoDB]

I've already try the following, according to [this tutorial](http://php.net/manual/en/mongo.queries.php):

```
$cursor = $this->collection->find(array("tags" => array('$in' => "Canada")));
var_dump($cursor);
```

but it is returning an empty cursor.

I would appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Please do NOT provide images to show your data structure, since this would require people trying to help you to type it in manually. Rather, provide a sample BSON document. In general, querying for an array item is pretty straightforward. In shell terms  `db.yourCollection.find({"tags":/Canada/i})`, using a case insensitive regex search.

Comment: Noted and thanks for the tip.